# How to disable the No SIM Card Installed warning in iPad when using it without SIM?

Tags: ipad, sim

I have not managed to find a way to disable the warning `No Sim Card Installed` while using iPad Air without sim-card. I disabled using Mobile data in all parts of settings. I have done this now in three generation of iPads unsuccessfully. The notice window looks like this

[image]

How can you disable the warning No Sim Card in iPads?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To prevent this message you can continually keep your iPad in Airplane Mode. Whilst not recommended to be on all the time, it provides a solution. If you turn WiFi on you should have no issues using internet features and services.

Comment: While this works, it is not suggested to use iPad with Airplane mode turned on for eternity.

Comment: @NimeshNeema why?

Comment: @KevinGrabher, Airplane mode technically turn off **all** radio communications. With the stated solution, you are left only with Wi-Fi enabled. While can turn on Wi-Fi and Bluetooth in Airplane mode, radios like GPS still remain non-functional and thus create a potentially undesirable situation. Refer to [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/98659/279727) discussion.

Comment: -1 if I had the rep. This doesn't make the error message go away

Answer (score 7):

Ask Siri to "turn off mobile data".
Worked for me on an iPad 4 with iOS 10.2.
Found in [this Apple discussion](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6548387?answerId=26857356022#26857356022).

Comment: Best answer for my old 4th gen iPad. Odd that you can't get into the cellular data menu in settings with no SIM card.

Answer (score 3):

You will need a SIM card to do this. You can borrow one for a brief period.

With the correct sized SIM card, remove the SIM card holder from the iPad, using the SIM card ejector tool (one is provided in-the-box with a new iPad).

**With the iPad turned on:**

1. Insert the SIM card into the holder and refit the holder into the iPad.
2. Go to `Settings app → Mobile Data`.
3. Turn off Mobile Data.
4. Remove the SIM card from the iPad.
5. Hold down the Power button and slide the on-screen Power Off switch and wait for the iPad to power off.

The next time you turn the iPad on, it will not look for a SIM card so will not give you the **SIM card not installed** notification

Comment: On iPhone 6 this is now Settings → Cellular → Cellular Data, but it doesn't work.  "No SIM Card Installed" reappears as soon as you remove the card

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem with:

1. Turn on Airplane Mode
2. Turn on WiFi and Bluetooth
3. Turn off Airplane Mode
4. After this Cellular Data will be on so turn it off.

---

The disadvantage with this method is the fact that you can't use Cellular Data.

Answer (score -1):

You can tell Siri to turn off Mobile Data or turn it off in settings.

> I solved the issue on my 1st-gen mini (on iOS 8.0.2) by telling Siri to "turn off mobile data" and now it just says "iPad" in the status bar, instead of "No Sim".

([Source](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6548387?answerId=26857356022#26857356022))

Comment: Thanks for your answer. How does this difference from [this answer?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/265381/310476)

Answer (score -1):

I solved the problem just by removing the sim tray. Whilst not the most practical solution the iPad wont display the warning as it cant detect if a SIM card is inserted.